# R : confidence interval being partially displayed with ggplot2 (using geom_smooth())

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, smoothing

I have the following simple R code:

```
disciplines <- c("A","C","B","D","E")
# To stop ggplot from imposing alphabetical ordering on x-axis
disciplines <- factor(disciplines, levels=disciplines, ordered=T)

d1 <- c(0.498, 0.521, 0.332, 0.04, 0.04)
d2 <- c(0.266, 0.202, 0.236, 0.06, 0.06)
d3 <- c(0.983, 0.755, 0.863, 0.803, 0.913)
d4 <- c(0.896, 0.802, 0.960, 0.611, 0.994)

df <- data.frame(disciplines, d1, d2, d3, d4)
df.m <- melt(df)
graph <- ggplot(df.m, aes(group=1,disciplines,value,colour=variable,shape=variable)) +
         geom_point() +
         geom_smooth(stat="smooth", method=loess, level=0.95) +
         scale_x_discrete(name="Disciplines") +
         scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1,1), name="Measurement")
```

The output looks like this:
[image]

Why does the confidence interval not display along the entire curve?

Notes:

1. I don't want to have `fullrange=TRUE` because that just yields a single straight blue line instead of the zigzag shape in the current output.
2. I am comparing this plot with another plot which has negative values in the (0,-1] range, which is why the y-axis has `limits=c(-1,1)`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the first three segments of the confidence interval, the top end of the range is at least partially out of bounds (the bounds being [-1, 1], not the slightly expanded range on the axes). `ggplot`'s default behavior is to not display any object that is partially out of bounds.  You can fix this by adding `oob=scales::rescale_none` to `scale_y_continuous`:

```
library(scales)
graph <- ggplot(df.m, aes(group=1,disciplines,value,colour=variable,shape=variable)) +
         geom_point() +
         geom_smooth(stat="smooth", method=loess, level=0.95) +
         scale_x_discrete(name="Disciplines") +
         scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-1,1), name="Measurement", oob=rescale_none)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you for the quick answer. I was staring at the emtpy bottom half of the y-axis, thinking something was wrong about that ... but I forgot that the upper limit was 1.0! The confidence interval goes just a wee bit beyond that. I have a feeling that your answer has saved me many hours of Googling in my R-infested future.

Comment: Note you will need to explicitly load the `scales` package.

Comment: @Noam Ross, in `?continuous_scale` it only says "oob: 
What to do with values outside scale limits (out of bounds)?`. Where can I read more about "What to do"?

Comment: @Henrik: It's poorly documented.  `oob=` takes the name of a function that takes the out-of-bounds values and modifies them.  The functions are in the `scales` package.  The default (`censor`) removes the values. `rescale_none` leaves them alone.  Others (`rescale_*`) modify the values in various ways.  For instance, `rescale_max` will set all out-of-bound values to the maximum of the axis.

Answer (score 5):

A better documented, and perhaps more intuitive, solution would be to simply use `coord_cartesian`:

```
ggplot(df.m, aes(group=1,disciplines,value,colour=variable,shape=variable)) +
         geom_point() +
         geom_smooth(stat="smooth", method=loess, level=0.95) +
         scale_x_discrete(name="Disciplines") +
         coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-1,1))
```